# how to automove any node in cytoscape js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I use cytoscape js automove extention, I can move two node together:

```
cy.automove({
    nodesMatching: cy.$('#a'),
    reposition: 'drag',
    dragWith: cy.$('#b')
});
```

But I must specify the node `#a` and `#b`, now I need whenever I move any node, its neighborhood move together, not a special node.

So I try this:

```
<style>
    #cy{
        width:600px;
        height:800px
    }
</style>
<script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
<script src="cytoscape-automove.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
<script>
var cy = cytoscape({

  container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in

  elements: [ // list of graph elements to start with
    { // node a
      data: { id: 'a' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'b' }
    },
    { // node c
      data: { id: 'c' }
    },
    { // node d
      data: { id: 'd' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' }
    },
    { // edge cd
      data: { id: 'cd', source: 'c', target: 'd' }
    }
  ],

  style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': '#566',
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-color': '#bcc',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],

  layout: {
    name: 'grid',
    rows: 1
  },
  boxSelectionEnabled:true,
   panningEnabled: true,
   selectionType:"additive"
});

cy.on("drag",function(evt){
    var node=evt.target;
    cy.automove({
        nodesMatching: node.neighbourhood().nodes(),
        reposition: 'drag',
        dragWith: node
    });
});
</script>
```

The result is once I move node `#a`, node `#b` will not move together.But I move the node `#a` again, `#b` is moved but the position is wrong, it is too far.

So does the `dragWith` must be a special one? What if I want to move any one?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var i = 0;
cy.unbind("tapdrag");
cy.unbind("tapend");

cy.bind("tapdrag", "node", function(evt){
    if (i = 0) {
        i = 1;
        var node = evt.target;
        var target = cy.edges("[source = '" + node.id() + "']").target();
        cy.automove({
             nodesMatching: target,
             reposition: 'drag',
             dragWith: node
        });
    }
});

cy.bind("tapend", "node", function(evt) {
    i = 0;
});
```

Comment: no,if just mouse down on a node then move mouse at once will not trigger the 
 event 'taphold',but mouse down on a node and hold 2 second will trigger it.I need move other nodes together when I drag a node

Comment: closer to the answer,but not perfect,once I move node #a,the #b is moving,but it is too far,#a move 1px,#b move 10px.

Comment: what is the difference between drag and tapdrag?

Comment: Cytoscape named it that way in the documentation: http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/user-input-device-events

Comment: Maybe try out all the different user events, which make sense. Surely one will do as you wish. I think the false position comes from the event firing too often.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168709/discussion-between-stephan-t-and-nod).